# Offline iOS Web App says it requires an internet connection, even though it doesn't?

Tags: ios, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app, iphone-web-app

I'm trying to make an iOS Offline Web App (the web pages that are saved to the home screen and are a bit difficult to tell from native iOS apps).

My app consists of just two files:

**index.html**

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
            alert("Welcome to the site.");
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

**cache.manifest**

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# Version 0.0.2
```

If I navigate to the page in mobile Safari, it properly pops open the alert. If I put it into airplane mode, turn off wifi, force quit safari, and restart my iPhone, mobile Safari loads from the cache and pops open the alert just fine.

If I then save the page to my Home Screen (give it the name "Repo", for example), then attempt to open it, it'll pop open this error message:

> **Cannot Open Repo**
>
> Repo could not be opened because it is not connected to the Internet.

What's going on here? Why is mobile safari properly loading it from the cache, but the moment I try saving and opening it, it tells me it needs an Internet connection?

Comment: I think you must fetch data from internet again after you saved your page to the home screen. And then try opening it offline Have you tried that?

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution to this or reason why it's happening? I've just encountered the same issue.

Comment: @Findiglay - Nope. I decided there was a bug in that version Mobile Safari and this just wasn't going to work. Maybe it works in iOS 10, now that that's released?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare this seemed to be happening because of a request failing - although it seems a bit of a sledgehammer to disable the entire app because of one request failing.

Comment: Same with me. I think it's service worker fetch problem, unstalling the PWA solved the problem for me.